# Why did we need to learn mongoose js?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I search youtube for a project with express js and MongoDB. In most videos, the project is done with mongoose js. So my question is why do I need to learn mongoose?

Comment: MongoDB is a database. It has driver implementations in many languages. One of the most popular ones for node is mongoose.

Comment: It's just an ORM library. sql has sequelize for node or flask + django for python. Mongodb has mongoose for node. You could go without it if you want.

Comment: You can use MongoDB NodeJS Driver, instead of Mongoose ODM library - you have the option.

Comment: @super, mongoose is not mainly a MongoDB driver, it is a ODM/ORM library.

Comment: In principle it is a matter of taste if yo use such frameworks - I am not really a fan of them and prefer to work on MongoDB natively. However, if you attempt to learn programming by watching YouTube videos, then such framework might be useful for you (sorry, please don't feel offended by my statement)

Answer (score 1):

As MongoDB is a document-based NoSQL database, it does not give support for many features like hooks, index, etc. You have to code for everything that you need. While using mongoose, it does the job. you just need to use its syntax and it can manage your data for MongoDB in a very sufficient and coding-friendly way. It is a ODM for MongoDB which manages Documents as a Objects in memory